# Global git hook

Tags: git, hook

Is it possible to hook all ways of creating git repo? So I can run script when repo is cloned, initialized… (are there any other ways, except moving/copying folder?).

My intention is to track all repos, so I don't need to go through all dirs to run some action (mainly `git status` as I sometimes forget to commit changes and `git gc --auto`).

Answer (score 5):

Hooks are (currently) exclusively configured per-repository, so there can be no active hooks before a repository is created.

If you just want to initialize some repository specific settings identically for all new repositories you might be able to use the [repository template mechanism](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html#_template_directory).

By using your own template you can

- install activated hooks (by providing a `<template‑dir>/hooks/<hook‑name>` file),
- set configuration variables (by providing a `<template‑dir>/config` file), and
- configure per-repository exclude rules or attributes (by providing a `<template‑dir>/info/exclude` or `<template‑dir/info/attributes>` file).

Any configuration file that lives in a `.git` directory can be placed in a template to serve as the initial copy for that file in new repositories initialized from the template. I suppose you could even provide initial objects and refs.

Once you have a template directory made up with your customizations you must tell `git init` and `git clone` where to find it. This can be done explicitly with the `--template` option (Git 0.99.4 or later), or implicitly with the `GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` environment variable (Git 1.5.0 or later), or implicitly by setting the `init.templatedir` configuration variable in the “global” (per-user) or “system” Git configuration files (i.e. `~/.gitconfig` or `/etc/gitconfig` (varies by installation); Git 1.7.1 or later).

Comment: Thank for answer, but it is not what I was looking for: I want to track all repos, I added line about my intention to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "track" git repos (as in "ask some central referential the list of currently active git repo).
Each git repo is independent from another.

Two solutions might be considered:

- a git template as in Chris's answer, with one of the [client-side hooks](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) able, on the first use, to register the git repo in some "central" file.
  That file would then be read by an external script (external to git), in order to make the relevant `git status` or `git gc` that you want.
- if all your git repos are declared under the same common directory, you could declare a global parent git repo and add all the sub-repos as **[submodules](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)**.
  Since [git1.7.0](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.7.0.txt), `git status` knows when a submodule contains uncommitted changes.

Comment: Note: on `git submodules`, there is a fairly complete introduction on this: http://longair.net/blog/2010/06/02/git-submodules-explained